# missing props in certain pages and cant use history.push in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a ticket booking web project and put a history.push on the navbar. when I was on the home page, the push history on the navbar still worked, but when I switched to the detailed movie page, the push history on the navbar didn't work, and it reads undefined. when on the home page, the props on the navbar are read in full with the object, but when on the movie page the props details on the navbar are not readable, even though it is a component class.

Does anyone have the same problem as me, what's the solution?
i was use withRouter here..

Comment: share your code?

Comment: this is the error
`
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
   94 |      }
   95 | 
   96 |      handleProfile = () => {
>  97 |        this.props.history.push('/profile')
      | ^   98 |      }
   99 | 
  100 |      handleHome = () =>{`